# What do you call someone who is used by people behind the scenes?

Tags: single-word-requests

The true people in power need a pretty face to represent their agenda.

What do you call such an empty person ?

Comment: Look at Wikipedia's article "Power Behind the Throne".  It covers this historically and has a few links to other relevant articles.

Comment: Interestingly, I initially interpreted the headline to mean that you were looking for the name of someone who "worked behind the scenes" for someone in a position of power.

Answer (score 1):

**puppet**  should be what you are looking for.

```
definition by The Merriam-Webster's Collegiate® Dictionary
```

> one whose acts are controlled by an outside force or influence
>
> e.g.  **a puppet ruler**

Answer (score 0):

A figurehead. "a person who is head of a group, company, etc., in title but actually has no real authority or responsibility." Dictionary.com

Comment: That's different. The president of Germany or India as well as the Queen of England are figureheads. Bit they aren't puppets.

Comment: @Logophile A figurehead may or may not be a puppet (as a puppet may or may not be a figurehead), but she is the face the public sees and represents someone's agenda rather than her own will, which was the essence of the question when first posted.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I take the question to imply that the public is unaware that they are being sold a charade, which is not the case in the 3 cases I mentioned. The figurehead knows it too. So no agenda can be really advanced. Any examples of a figurehead who is a puppet and an agenda got advanced?

Comment: @Logophile I think Philippe Pétain, France's chief of state during the Vichy Republic, became a figurehead after 1942.